# what is the difference between *.extension and .extension?

Tags: git

I am using git and in the .gitignore I found *.local and .DS_Store(mac). what are the differences and (if you know) what are all the possible format for .gitignore?

Comment: Why not read [their documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.name` is not a pattern, not an extension, it's a filename. It just happens that the filename starts with a dot.

There is a tradition in Unix to name [hidden files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) with the leading dot. It's only a tradition, it isn't built into OS kernels, but most file managers follow it and hide files with the leading dot from lists by default.

Because of this hidden configuration files are called "dot files".

Comment: Thanks! I knew the hidden files, but had no idea about the naming conventions of unix. Also, what other types of selectors does the git have?

Comment: @Hackcraft_ `.gitignore` supports a [complex language](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format). The part "*An asterisk "`*`" matches anything except a slash. The character "`?`" matches any one character except "`/`". The range notation, e.g. `[a-zA-Z]`, can be used to match one of the characters in a range.*" is actually perfectly standard; see the section **Shell Patterns** in [`man ash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash) and [`man dash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash).

Comment: @Hackcraft_ See also **pathspec** in [`git help glossary`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).